# Creating multiple QGraphicsItemGroup groups when the number of groups is unknown

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create multiple QGraphicsItemGroup groups dynamically based on specific condition and I don't know how to do so. The items are points, I want to group points based on a specific condition. The condition is whether the points are close to each other.

I can make the first group but then I don't know how to continue.
The problem is that the number of groups is not known.

```
int c=1;
foreach( QGraphicsItem * item, list )
{
    if(c<list.count()){
        QPoint current_pt;
        int current_manhattanLength;
        current_pt.setX(list[c]->scenePos().x());
        current_pt.setY(list[c]->scenePos().y());

        current_manhattanLength=current_pt.manhattanLength();
        previous_pt.setX(list[c-1]->scenePos().x());
        previous_pt.setY(list[c-1]->scenePos().y());
        previous_manhattanLength=previous_pt.manhattanLength();

        if (qAbs(current_manhattanLength- previous_manhattanLength)<=15)
        {
            group->addToGroup(list[c]);
            group->addToGroup(list[c-1]);
        }
        c=c+1;

    }//end of if c counter
}//end first foreach
```

Comment: Do you meet the condition only once per group?

Comment: The condition must be ture between group members i updated the question have a look at the condition.

Comment: You can create a vector of groups and dynamically add groups to it. But without knowing the exact kind of condition it is difficult to be more specific with it.

Comment: To avoid potential XY problems, you might want to describe what your goal is; i.e. *why* do you want to place these items into groups?  What behavior do you hope to obtain by doing so?